# How do we handle conflicts with the Anime and Movies sites?

Tags: discussion, scope, anime, site-rec

There are now Stack Exchange sites about [anime & manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) and [movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). Questions about SF anime, manga or movies could therefore be on-topic on two sites.

1. My understanding is that a question that could be addressed by someone should be exposed if possible. Ideally, I think cross-listing a sci-fi movie question across both sites might provide a question with the most exposure. However, I am not sure the StackExchange architecture would support this.
2. If #1 is not possible or is against the policy of SE sites, how do we handle questions for Sci-Fi movies? Should they all be moved to this SF&F site? I am not sure what the best solution is that makes sure that a sci-fi movie question is answered.

Is anyone familiar with any other cases of site overlap and how they have been dealt with? If the overlap forces drastic changes to these sites, should works be split up into separate media sites like Movies & TV or separate genre sites like SF&F?

Comment: [Related Area 51 discussion](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/books-is-a-bad-organizational-name-for-a-proposal-overlaps-with-sci-fi-and-other) (from before “Books” had been renamed to “Literature”)

Comment: See also the [literature.se version of this question](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/20/) and the [movies.se version of this question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2/scifi-movies-overlap).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Short version: Yes, there's some overlap. It's not a problem. Do not cross-post.

---

Long version:

This won't be the first time or the last time there are sites overlapping topics. It's bound to happen: sites are defined in terms of communities at least as much as topics.

To give an existing example I'm familiar with:

- There's a site for [computer users](https://superuser.com/) and a site for [professional administrators](https://serverfault.com/).
- There's a site about [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), a site about [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), a site about [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

One family of sites is defined by role, the other one by object. The topics overlap. It's pretty much the same situation as with SF (defined by genre) compared to [Literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature) (now defunct) and [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) and [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) (defined by media).

Most questions on SF movies will be on-topic on both sites. It's up to the asker to **choose** where to post.

Cross-posting is [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073). (Strictly speaking, that's multi-posting: a question is only present on one site, the SE platform does not support cross-posting by design.) It might be ok occasionally to ask similar questions on both sites, but the questions should be tailored to each audience.

In time, I expect we'll have guidelines as to which questions are better asked on which site — for example visual effects are likely to be more of a Movies.SE topic, whereas unraveling time travel paradoxes is likely to be more of a Scifi.SE topic. But there will inevitably be some overlap that can be asked on either site indifferently.

Comment: I agree, you post here because you love scifi. If you post on Literature, its because perhaps you love literature in general. Either way, we're part of a network, so we're not competing anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I said cross-post, I do not mean double posting, i.e., posting a unique question on both sites. I was thinking maybe there was some way a question could be cross-listed on multiple sites to get maximum exposure to the right audience. By cross-listing I mean there would exist one question under both sites. Answers on both sites would co-exist in one place. I am guessing that the SE architecture does not support this feature.

Comment: A better solution would've been merge lit.se and movies.se into this and made it fiction.se

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: Nope, that'd be WAY too broad.

Comment: Multi posting is discouraged... what about unintentional duplicate from other site ? If I ask here a question answered on movies, will it be closed as duplicate ?

Comment: @Kalissar There is no notion of closing as a duplicate of a question on another site. As long as the questions are on-topic on both sites (which will be the case if it's a question about an SF movie), they'll stay.

Comment: @RoyalFlush:   Not sure if that was tongue-in-cheek, but not all literature and movies are fiction.   (Just the good stuff)

Answer (score -4):

All questions on the Movies site that are given a "science fiction" tag should be migrated to the sci-fi stack as a matter of course.

There may be individual cases where those questions are better suited to Movies but I'm struggling to think of any relevant examples.

Comment: I'm afraid, though, that is something only the people over on [movies.se] can actually decide about as it lies entirely beyond the responsibility of this site.

Comment: I stand by my assessment.

Comment: Of course you do, I'm just saying that it is entirely fultile on this meta question here.

Comment: @tars - Many things are futile on Meta.