# Should questions about Twin Peaks be migrated to the Movies and TV beta?

Tags: discussion, migration

There is currently [one question about Twin Peaks](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18/what-was-bob-in-twin-peaks) here on Science Fiction and Fantasy, but no tag for the series.  Then when I posted a question here about the series it was suggested I should have asked it on the Movies and TV beta, since whilst the series contains sci-fi and fantasy elements, it isn't a good fit here.

Movies & TV have [a tag for the series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twin-peaks), and currently have three questions there.  So should the remaining Twin Peaks question here be migrated?

Comment: There's likely no tag because the system periodically removes tags that have been used only once.

Comment: @Keen Okay, I guess that covers that point of my question but it still leaves the question concerning which of the two SE sites is best for posting Twin Peaks questions, or are both okay?

Comment: I'm a little confused in the first place.  While I didn't watch _Twin Peaks_, my impression was that it was unusual, but not really in the realm of SF&F.

Comment: @TangoOversway That's probably not surprising.  The setting isn't fantasy or sci-fi, but as the series develops it becomes clear that something supernatural oozes its way into the plot with increasing frequency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Twin Peaks on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11208/is-twin-peaks-on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

On the general of the overlap between this site and Movies & TV, please read [How do we handle conflicts with the Anime and Movies sites?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-literature-and-movies-sites).

We would only migrate a question if it was off-topic, or at least borderline and in need of more attention. [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18/what-was-bob-in-twin-peaks) is firmly on-topic here, since it's about a supernatural element.

About [your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/which-episodes-of-twin-peaks-mention-the-concept-of-tulpa): it was on-topic here. In the (deleted) comments, I only see that someone questioned whether Twin Peaks was sf, but other commenters contradicted him, and it was determined that the question was on-topic. But you reposted on Movies & TV, and [cross-posting is strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073), so we [migrated](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/which-episodes-of-twin-peaks-mention-the-concept-of-tulpa) your question at your request.

Comment: This is a true reflection of events I guess, but it leave me with the feeling or impression that Twin Peaks questions weren't really welcome here or there was some ambiguity concerning that.  Thanks for the conflict reference.

Comment: Having read the reference I'm getting the impression that questions that directly relate to the 'fantasy' or 'sci-fi' elements of the series have a happy home here or on M&TV whilst questions concerning things like the love triangle between Lucy, Andy and Dick or choice of directors, camera-work or whatever belong only on that latter.  Am I right?

Comment: @AntonChanning There's some overlap. For works that are borderline SF, we try to be inclusive. A guideline when choosing a site is who you want to reach: if you think your question is best answered by SF fans, ask here; if you thinks it's best answered by movie fans, ask on [movies.se].