# A lot of film based questions

Tags: discussion

I'm a "current" user on [*Movies & TV* SE Site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions), yet relatively new to SciFi & Fantasy. I see a lot of questions here which would and could be more easily answered over there, such as "ID this movie" type questions. I'm curious why these types of questions aren't directed to that site from here more often ... in fact, I don't remember too many *ever* being redirected from here. I realize there is a huge segment of the movie industry which is dedicated to SciFi & Fantasy, which would make for a corresponding overlap. These questions are on-topic here, but would make a LOT more sense being there. **I'm just wondering the reasoning or why it isn't more prevalent to move them.**

Comment: Why would it *"make a LOT more sense"* for a sci-fi movie question to be migrated to Movies?

Comment: Well, because those questions are about movies? Movies fit in with movies? Like/like? I do get there is overlap, as I stated. Questions about Sci-Fi movies make some sense here in that aspect. But identification of Sci-Fi movies would fit there a lot better than here, it would seem to me.

Comment: Replace the word "movies" with "sci-fi" and you've got the same argument for leaving them here. I don't think you've made a convincing case.

Comment: @Paulster2 Calm down.  Voting on Meta is different from the Main sites: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites

Comment: Also related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3691 http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2782 http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1875 - I'm close to VTCing this as a dupe as it's a topic that has been covered a lot in the past.

Comment: Personally I agree with the opposite contention, they should auto-move all science fiction movies questions to here, where the experts are.

Comment: They're not migrated because they're on-topic. Since they're on-topic on both, the questions can be asked on *either* stack (it's strongly discouraged to ask on both). The OP can choose where they think they'll find a better audience for a question.

Comment: @phantom42 ... *That*, at least, makes good sense. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @DarthSatan ... thanks for pointing those out. I looked for some, but my Google-Fu through the search function is lacking.

Comment: Please don't get personal with comments (to @Richard). Just make your case as best as you can and let the community discuss it with you.

Comment: This has repeatedly been adressed in various various meta posts. The bottom line is, overlap will naturally occur and as long as a question is on-topic on both sites, it is up to ones own discretion where to ask it and you don't migrate on-topic stuff.

Comment: And as to your example: **NO, if there's anything [movies.se] does *not* need, it's more ID-stuff** (yet, I would personally welcome questions about the *Dark Knight* trilogy on a site where they're actually on-topic ;-)).

Comment: @SkyCaptain ... I agree MTV.SE doesn't need more ID questions, that was just an example. I guess it really doesn't matter anyway as MTV.SE is already slated for migration. They are just waiting on the new designer to take over duties, which is supposed to happen in Feb, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

Given that there's just as good a case to be made that all SF-related questions on Movies:SE should be migrated here, the consensus (for the time being) seems to be to let sleeping dogs lie, at least until Movies:SE comes out of beta and we start looking at formal migration paths.

[image]

As has been discussed ([at](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites), [considerable](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3691/when-does-a-movie-question-get-migrated-to-movies-and-tv), [length](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/should-questions-about-twin-peaks-be-migrated-to-the-movies-and-tv-beta)),  since we have both a Movies:SE and a Science-Fiction:SE site, **it's best left down to the individual user to decide which would be most likely to provide the best response to their question.**