# How should we deal with questions asking about the meaning of words in a sci-fi setting?

Tags: discussion

We have also seen the questions. So I'm not going to directly link to them here. But what is the consensus on how we should deal with questions that ask for explanations of English language words used in a sci-fi setting.

An example question would be -"What does left turn mean in this scene in the Matrix?"

The questions seem to follow a similar pattern.

- Created by a new/low level user.
- Not a lot of information in the question other than a direct quote and maybe an image.
- The user raises a number of questions about the same sci-fi film/series/book in a short time period.
- Questions can generally be answered by anyone with a good understanding of the English language.
- The questions are not directly related to the sci-fi property but are more questions about the English language itself.

Should them questions be flagged to close, should the user be directed to another stack overflow or what do people think should be done.

Comment: Should be closed as a dupe of https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/58193 but seeing as this keeps coming up I’m willing to let the discussion stay up for a bit to see what people’s thoughts on nowadays.

Comment: It's a duplicate of a well-voted question with no dissenting answers. Why leave it up so the same people can post the same answers?

Comment: "*We have all seen the question*". Have we? A month from now those questions will be buried off the front page and people reading this won't have the faintest clue what you're talking about.

Comment: So in theory there would be nothing that would stop anyone posting lots of questions in this vane, and they would all be allowed? I'd not seen the duplicate of this post, but if it's already been discussed I will keave it for a bit and then delete it

Comment: @A.Steer - If someone wants to post lots of on-topic questions, do we want to stop them? I note that they've posted several that they've then deleted when they see how elementary they are (and how many downvotes they've attracted), so the system is working just fine already.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/conversation/english-questions-may-require-story-context

Comment: @Alex - Exactly so. Users on other stacks wouldn't know the scifi context of the quote and might get it wrong. Better to keep them here

Comment: There does seem to be a difference between people who are voting/commenting on the posts on the main site against those who are commenting in meta. Several of the original posts have several down votes/are getting closed as well as having comments against them stating why is the user doing this. While everyone dosent have to use meta it does seem a bit of a disconnect between what we are seeing and what we are saying.

Comment: @A.Steer - On-topic doesn't mean that a question will get (or deserve) upvotes. I tend to downvote every *"What is the first example of this trope"*  question, but I don't usually vote to close them, because that action is reserved for Qs that are off-topic