# Is Twin Peaks on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Just wondering if David Lynch's second season of *Twin Peaks* is on topic at the site? It has science fiction aspects in my opinion -- do others feel the same? If I recall correctly, a question about *Twin Peaks* being on topic might have been asked before, but it would have been about season one, which is rather different than season two.

Comment: I've not seen it but the FAQ on Twinpeaks.org talks about aliens, the supernatural and "Scifi elements" that were included in the first and second seasons; http://www.twinpeaks.org/faqgen.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *Twin Peaks* is firmly on topic. Without spoiling the plot, both seasons of the original series contain supernatural (fantastical) elements, as does the new series.