# Would questions tagged 'Science-Fiction' in Movies&TV fracture the network?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the [Movies&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) beta site, they have the [science-fiction tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction).

The tag happens to be the 6<sup>th</sup> most popular tag, and is the most popular 'genre' on the site<sup>[1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)</sup>.

In general when a beta sites start, they should not fracture the network; i.e. if a question can be answered in an existing site, then it belongs in the existing site; as per the [Area51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

**What are the options here?**

Do we:

- Suggest to remove that tag, and have all sci-fi related questions migrated here
- Leave it as is, and take a case-by-case approach
- Do nothing as my concern is not valid
- Other

Answer (score 12):

I pick

> Do nothing as my concern is not valid

This was discussed ages ago: [How do we handle conflicts with the Anime and Movies sites?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/626/1027) And I believe discussed since then.  There are sci-fi and fantasy movies, they're on topic for both sites.  Don't crosspost questions, and there's no problem.  Just pick which site you want to post your questions to.

Comment: But being that *that* site is in beta, should we have some sort of preference; similar to where the quasar question went? http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/why-was-the-quasar-question-migrated-to-physics-se-instead-of-astronomy-se

Comment: @Mooz The only one who needs a preference is you yourself and this preference can be entirely different from any other user's. That other question is related to *migration*, which is an entirely different topic on its own, but as long as the question is already asked an on-topic, there's nothing to be done about it (except if the OP decides to migrate, of course).

Comment: @mooz Last I heard, they're in the queue to graduate. Dunno what's taking SE so long to do it.

Comment: @Keen: Yes they are, [here](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1268/13707) is some evidence, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237472/where-have-the-site-self-evaluations-gone#comment778914_237588) is some more.

Answer (score 7):

The 3rd point, i.e.

> Do nothing as my concern is not valid

In fact this statement from you question is already wrong:

> if a question can be answered in an existing site, then it belongs in the existing site; as per the Area51 FAQ.

This is stated nowhere in the Area51 FAQ, the only points related to this I could find are

> In general, if a site makes sense as part of a bigger site, it's better to have one big site than a bunch of little niche sites. Site X should be subsumed by site Y if:
>
> - Almost all X questions are on-topic for site Y
> - If Y already exists, it already has a tag for X, and nobody is complaining
> - You're not creating such a big group that you don't have enough experts to answer all possible questions
> - There's a high probability that users of site Y would enjoy seeing the occasional question about X

But all those points only apply if the whole topic of the beta site would be on-topic here, which is clearly not the case, as questions about Science Fiction movies make up for only a small part of all the questions on Movies & TV.

So as discussed already in the [relevant](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/626/23386) meta [sites](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/49) it is entirely upto each and every user himself where he asks a question about a Science Fiction or Fantasy movie if it is on-topic on both sites, as long as the same user doesn't deliberately cross-post questions.

---

And as to the genre tags on Movies & TV, those are really only used for ID-questions and general questions about the genre, not for questions about specific movies, so its state as the "most popular" genre on the site is debatable anyway. But you can have those ID-questions if you want. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Leave as-is and do it on a case-by-case basis**.

A question relating to the plot of a sci-fi movie or TV show properly belongs here, as does a question relating to the explicitly sci-fi elements of it.

However, and from looking at the [Tour](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) page of the beta site, it also aims to cover the following elements:

> - Questions about a Movie/TV show's production
> - The works of a director / an actor / a writer related to Movies/TV

This class of question *doesn't* belong here, *even* if it is relating to a work in the sci-fi genre.  It's appropriate to leave these on the Movies & TV SE.

Comment: This is contradicting to established SE policy and practiced policy on the sites in question as pointed out in existing meta discussions. Questions relating to the plot of sci-fi movies don't "properly belong here", they properly belong on both sites and its up to the asker's discretion which one he choses (as long as he doesn't chose both).

Comment: From *our* help center, listed among the types of questions that should be asked here: "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information". BTS questions were also [discussed on meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2944/5184), and are on-topic here (provided the work is SF/F).

Answer (score -4):

All questions on the Movies site that are given a "science fiction" tag should be migrated to here as a matter of course.

There may be individual cases where it's better suited to Movies but I'm struggling to think of any relevant examples.

Comment: You might want to add your views as an answer to the relevant meta discussion which they currently contradict: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/626/23386.

Comment: @SkyCaptain - I'm guessing it'll be as popular there as it is here...

Comment: Maybe (and I hope so ;-)), but at least there is the more appropriate place to make an attempt at changing the overall policy.

Answer (score -8):

Other. Let's fracture the network. Make this a site for written sf, and move all that other crap elsewhere.