# Questions about Mad Max : Fury Road on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Would questions about Fury Road be on-topic here, or would they be better suited for the [Movie Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Why would they not be on-topic?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Post apocalyptic fiction is an [established sub-genre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalyptic_and_post-apocalyptic_fiction) of science fiction. As such, there's no reason not to discuss the movie here on the site.

However, being a movie, it is *also* on-topic in Movies.SE. [A common guideline](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites) here is that questions about plot and characters, and especially questions about the SFnal elements in the film, are warmly welcomed here, while questions about production, visual effects and the process of *making* movies is more fitting over there, but it's a soft guideline, and usually not a problem.

Just remember not to cross-post a question on both sites. That's discouraged.

Comment: @Daft I expanded the answer a bit with more guidance.

Comment: Just a note: questions about the production side of sci-fi movies *are* on topic here. You will likely find more experts on those things on M&TV, but possibly an expert who knows those details about a *specific* sci-fi property here, so YMMV.

Comment: And another note just to complete the circle, in the same way like questions about production, visual effects and the process of filmmaking are on topic here, questions about plot, characters and SFnal elements are on-topic over there. So afterall it is 100% your choice.

Comment: I was under the impression that [cross posting was **not** discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules)