# When to ask on SF&F and when to ask on Arqade?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I have a question about *Fallout 3* and I don't know if I should ask it on SF&F or [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

The question is

> Why does Moira insists on you getting a mine from Minefield?

Should this question be on SF&F or Arqade? Is it okay to post to both? Also is there a general guideline for which to ask where?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319. Also, [please don't cross-post questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626)

Comment: thanks, but in this specific instant what would you choose? because it is kinda both lore and gameplay related

Comment: Seems more like a gameplay element (e.g. a "plot coupon") than something relevant to this site.

Comment: It's lore/plot related, I don't see it as gameplay related in anyway (other than it being part of a quest)

Comment: If it's on-topic, then you can ask it wherever you like. I'd prefer you to ask it here, but that's because I'm biased

Comment: For the record, this one seems answerable based on [Moira's dialogue](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Minefield); "*I've heard stories about a ghost town that's just full of mines. Traders just call the place "Minefield." Sounds like the place for some fieldwork! Get in there, get back, and tell me all about it. And could you bring back a mine for my studies?*" - She wants ones from the Minefield to study.

Comment: @Valorum that still doesn't explain why it HAS to be from minefield, literally any Mine would give her the same data

Comment: @Dave - Yes, but she wants ones from that specific place because she thinks that'll help her to write her book. Maybe they have some special properties or maybe she just wants to examine one to make sure it's the same design as she's used to.

Comment: I've closed this meta as a duplicate of the FAQ on which video-game questions can be asked on SFF instead of Arqade. (The usual caveats apply on duplicate closure not being a bad thing.)

Answer (score 5):

The best site to ask your question depends on what kind of answer you are seeking. If you want to know how the game mechanics work, then Arqade is the place to go since [gameplay questions are off-topic in SF&F SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/7957). If you are curious about lore or narrative, then you can ask on either SF&F SE or Arqade, since both sites accept questions about the lore and narrative of the game.

However, you should choose only one site to post your question, as cross-posting is against Stack Exchange policy: "[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/162827)"

To help you decide, you might want to browse the existing questions about the *Fallout* games on both sites and see what kind of answers they have received.

Comment: While you're not wrong, ISTM that, given the diversity of the entire field of SF&F, one would have better odds finding someone with deep expertise in *Fallout* on Arqade than here.

Comment: @DavidW: I would argue that video games are similarly diverse, just in a different direction.